# Does OSX Lion come with iPhoto?

Tags: macos, photos.app

I need iPhoto, but I don't know if I deleted it or I just never had it to begin with.  I'm currently running OSX Lion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lion (or any other OS X operating system) doesn't come with iPhoto by default. However, iPhoto, iMovie, and Garageband are normally installed on new systems.

You'll have to install iPhoto if it's not on your system. Each new Mac does get some version of iLife, so you may be able to check from Apple the version of the OS that shipped with your hardware at http://apple.com/support/manuals and search to see what your options are.

Comment: Sofware Update should show whether you can re-download iPhoto for free.

Answer (score 0):

iPhoto and indeed the rest of the iLife range of apps is provided free of charge with new Mac hardware.  If you bought your Mac from new, then you will have either the discs/USB install stick with the software on, or a license for the apps against your Apple ID in the Mac App Store; the age of your Mac decides which install medium you were provided with.  If you bought your Mac 2nd hand, then unless it originally came with physical media that was also passed onto you, or was left installed on the OS, then you are out of luck.